# One internal php script for all of my pages

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need some help.

I've got some php code which I want on every page of my site. But if I want to edit something in it ill have to edit every section of code ,in that php code, on every page. Is there a way so I can only edit on file and it reflects on all of the others on the other pages.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php


if (!$_SESSION["valid_user"])
        {
        // User not logged in, redirect to login page
        echo '<gen id= mess>You need to login to use this!!!</gen>';    
        echo "<p><a href=\"login.php\">login</a></p>";
        }else{

// Member only content
// ...
// ...
// ...

// Display Member information
echo "<p>User ID: " . $_SESSION["valid_id"];
echo "<p>Username: " . $_SESSION["valid_user"];

// Display logout link
echo "<p><a href=\"logout.php\">Click here to logout!</a></p>";
}
?>
```

P.S: i was thinking that is may work (but it didnt):

```
include 'filename';

or

require 'filename';
```

Comment: You might need to use an absolute path - `include 'filename.php'` will only work if that file is in the same directory.

Comment: Your solution is the right one, make it a separate script and include it. Just make sure the path is correct.

Comment: include "something.php"; should work. This will insert the code of "something.php" where you write the include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) or [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) functions depending on your requirements:

```
require_once("filename.php")
include_once("filename.php")
```

These are likely to be most appropriate to what you want to do, because you only want a header once.

However, if you wanted to include something more than once, you can use:

```
require("filename.php")
include("filename.php")
```

This is not restricted to simply including parts of pages that you wish to include - You can also use these functions to include files that contain functions that you wish to make use of in other parts of your code.

Comment: Looks like your explanation was not helpful for a long time-span: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348655/whats-wrong-with-this-html-php-code - please take care when answering to such "basic" questions. It's often better to only place the manual links in a comment and not put guesses into answers.

Answer (score 0):

You simply place your script in ex. script.php.
And wherever you want it to include it :

```
require_once 'script.php';
```

That way you edit only one file. Happy coding :)